# SQL time in & time out clashes between any ids in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, time, between

I am trying to create two fields in my table that shows whether a vid's time clashes with ANY another vid's time, and which vid's clash.

SAMPLE DATA:

```
SELECT vid, timein, timeout
FROM mytable

vid timein                      timeout
1   2015-04-15 06:00:00.000     2015-04-16 17:00:00.000
2   2015-04-17 03:00:00.000     2015-04-17 18:00:00.000
3   2015-04-16 16:00:00.000     2015-04-17 06:00:00.000
4   2015-04-12 12:00:00.000     2015-04-12 22:00:00.000
5   2015-03-25 01:00:00.000     null
```

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
vid timein                      timeout                     Clash   Clashwith
1   2015-04-15 06:00:00.000     2015-04-16 17:00:00.000     CLASH   3
2   2015-04-17 03:00:00.000     2015-04-17 18:00:00.000     CLASH   3
3   2015-04-16 16:00:00.000     2015-04-17 06:00:00.000     CLASH   1, 2
4   2015-04-12 12:00:00.000     2015-04-12 22:00:00.000     OK
5   2015-03-25 01:00:00.000     null                        OK
```

WHAT I HAVE TRIED:

```
SELECT vid, timein, timeout,
CASE WHEN (SELECT tin.timein 
           FROM mytable tin 
           WHERE tin.vid = mytable.vid 
           AND mytable.timeout IS NOT NULL) 
           BETWEEN mytable.timein AND mytable.timeout
     THEN 'CLASH' 
     ELSE 'OK' 
     END AS inclash,
CASE WHEN (SELECT tout.timeout 
           FROM mytable tout 
           WHERE tout.vid = mytable.vid 
           AND mytable.timeout IS NOT NULL) 
           BETWEEN mytable.timein AND mytable.timeout
     THEN 'CLASH' 
     ELSE 'OK' 
     END AS outclash
FROM mytable
```

This doesn't work as it is giving a clash for all results, also i have no idea how to get the clash with column written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with one simple `apply()`, and to concatenate all clashing ids you can use xml trick:

```
select
    t1.vid,
    t1.[timein],
    t1.[timeout],
    case when c.Clashwith is not null then 'CLASH' else 'OK' end as Clash,
    c.Clashwith
from mytable as t1
    outer apply (
        select
            stuff(
                (
                    select ',' + cast(t2.vid as nvarchar(max))
                    from mytable as t2
                    where
                        t2.vid <> t1.vid and
                        t2.[timein] <= t1.[timeout] and
                        t2.[timeout] >= t1.[timein]
                     for xml path(''), type
                ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)')
            ,1,1,'') as Clashwith
    ) as c
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b90ae/8)</kbd>**

Comment: are you sure? it gives exact the same output on your test example

Comment: hey @Matt now this code is definetely incorrect, `or` part is not checking self joins, for example. I'll check code back again, please try to find an example on which my code is not working and we'll work it out.

Comment: You also have to check how nulls should be treated in this query. And please do not edit my answer.